# Google people API V1 extended properties

Tags: php, google-api

I'm upgrading our Google service wrapper (PHP) with the latest Google PHP client v2-2-2.

I'm trying to replace contact API with people API, but I can't get extended properties (NOT USER DEFINED PROPERTIES).

People API seems not manage this properties, any solutions ?

Thanks & bye.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation [Person.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) returns a [Person resource](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person)

Person resource does not contain the extended properties that are available in the [contacts api](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/reference#gd:extendedProperty)

> gd:extendedProperty
>   Contact entry uses an extended gd:extendedProperty, which stores client-specific properties (see: [Extended properties and projections](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/reference#ProjectionsAndExtended)).

You may want to consider adding it as a feature request [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:344199%2B)